# How would i validate a text field in html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, validation

I have a text field for a user to enter and examination number which is 4 digits long. How would I validate the text field to make sure the digits entered are exactly 4 digits (including a leading 0).

So far I have validated it so that it isn't left blank. 
Here's my Javascript:

```
function validateForm() 
{
    var result = true;

    var msg="";
    if (document.ExamEntry.name.value=="")
    {
        msg+="You must enter your name \n";
        document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
        document.getElementById('name').style.color="red";
        result = false;
    }
    if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value=="")
    {
        msg+="You must enter the subject \n";
        document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
        document.getElementById('subject').style.color="red";
        result = false;
    }



    if (document.ExamEntry.ExamNo.value=="")
    {
        msg+="You must enter your Examination number \n";
        document.ExamEntry.ExamNo.focus();
        document.getElementById('ExamNo').style.color="red";
        result = false;
    }


    if(msg=="")
    {

        return result;
    }
    {
    alert(msg)
    return result;
    }
}
```

Here's My html :

```
<body>
<h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
<form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
    <table width="50%" border="0">
        <tr>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="name">Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="subject">Subject</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="subject"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="ExamNo">Examination number</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="ExamNo"/></td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onClick="return validateForm();" /></td>
            <td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/^\d\d\d\d$/.test(document.ExamEntry.ExamNo.value)
```

It returns a boolean that check if ExamNo matches that regular expression (4-digit string).

Complete example:

```
if (!/^\d\d\d\d$/.test(document.ExamEntry.ExamNo.value))
    {
        msg+="Examination number should be 4-digit number. \n";
        document.ExamEntry.ExamNo.focus();
        document.getElementById('ExamNo').style.color="red";
        result = false;
    }
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of how you did it with blank values. Hope it helps.

Comment: You're welcome. Please select this answer as correct to help others with the same problem.

Comment: Because its school work, I have to explain how it works but i dont know how. I understands the stuff within the 'if' statement but i dont understand how  '(!/^\d\d\d\d$/.test(document.ExamEntry.ExamNo.value))' works?

Comment: Could you explain what '(!/^\d\d\d\d$/.test(document.ExamEntry.ExamNo.value))' does?

Comment: in javascript something inside `/ /` is an object regex. a regex is a sequence that forms a search pattern. `^` indicates the beginning of the string and `$` indicates the end. `\d` indicates a digit, so `^\d\d\d\d$ searches a string that starts, has 4 digits and ends.

The method .test tries that pattern with a string, which is the string you want to check.

Comment: Hi there, For my work i need to reference an I.T Professional and was wondering if you wouldn't mind me using you :)

Comment: Can I use your name in my worK?

Comment: Hi There, the next question i got for my work is to add a set of radio buttons to the form to accept a level of entry such as GCSE, AS or A2 then write a function that displays the level of entry to the user in an alert box so that the level can be confirmed or rejected.

Comment: I've make the radio buttons: 
   <tr>
    <td id='GCSE'>GCSE</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name=”level" value="GCSE"/><td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id='AS'>AS</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name=”level" value="AS"/><td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id='A2'>A2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name=”level" value="A2"/><td>
   </tr>

Comment: But I dont know how im to create a function that displays the level of entry to the user in an alert box so that the level can be confirmed or rejected.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931983/validating-radio-buttons-with-an-alert-box-so-it-can-be-either-accepted-or-rejec

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below link

http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/

This is a validation plugin and easy to use.

Comment: I need to do it within the javascript function i already have :)