# Validating Radio Buttons with an alert box so it can be either accepted or rejected

Tags: javascript, html, function, validation, radio-button

For my school work I have to add a set of radio buttons to the form to accept a level of entry such as GCSE, AS or A2. Then I have to write a javascript function that displays the level of entry to the user in an alert box so that the level can be confirmed or rejected. So far I have done the radio buttons but don't know how to do the function.

Heres my code so far: http://jsbin.com/hibutazide/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

you could give different id to every radio button, and then use `checked` property of them in javascript.

```
if(!document.getElementById('r1').checked && 
    !document.getElementById('r2').checked && 
    !document.getElementById('r3').checked){
 alert("you must choose a radio button");
}
```

Comment: Aha thanks, I worked it out using a different function and onclick